# Will CosmosDB route my query to multiple partitions when query has a range filter on the partition key field?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'd like to know if given a query (see belo) which has a range filter on the partition key field, will **CosmosDB route the query to the partitions allocated in the given range**, or **will send out to all the partitions instead**? I can't replicate this behavior in my dev. environment, otherwise I'd be happy to try out myself.

```
select *
from c
where c.partition_key_field >= "123" and c.partition_key_field <= "456"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cosmos DB uses hash-based partitioning vs. range-based so range filters like this will hit every physical partition versus a subset of them.

You can test this in a container that has > 10K RU/s by running a query like this in data explorer in the Cosmos Portal and then click the "Per-partition query metrics (CSV)" link in the query stats.

Comment: Will be there a different outcome if query uses a `IN` operator rather than a range filter? This is: `select * from d where d.partition_key_field in ("123", "345")`. I do see that the [How to query a container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/how-to-query-container#useful-example) document states that a `IN` operator in a query could reduce the scope of visited physical partitions - that's why I asked if maybe a range filter could have the same behavior. That said, thank you for sharing this info! Btw, I wish I can test out that behavior, but I don't have enough to data

Comment: @curiousguy_08 The number of logical partitions hit will depend on the number of values in the range. Using an IN limits the values and hence is better than a range. However if the number of values in IN and range are the same there is no difference. But keep in mind, that you have multiple logical partitions being read but they still may be on the same physical partition and hence the RU usage may differ depending on this as well. You can only control the logical partitioning. You cannot enforce your physical partitioning. Microsoft does this in the background for you.

Comment: FYI additional questions should be asked in a separate question; comments aren't intended for general discussion (or further answering of questions)

Comment: @curiousguy_08 - you don't need any data at all for this as all you are looking at is which partition(s) your queries get routed to. This will be the same for a collection with no data as one with data. So in the emulator you could create one with partition key of `/partition_key_field` and 100,000 autoscale max RU (to get 10 partitions) then compare the partitions visited for `=` / `IN`/ `BETWEEN`

Comment: Thank you @MartinSmith! I didn't know the emulator is capable of handling physical partitions.